# Determining an object's position from optical image

Tags: optics

Assuming your object is symmetric, is there a way to tell whether it is positioned at A'' or A' purely by recording its movement from A to either location?

(I'm experiencing polystyrene beads being pulled out of a microscope's focal plane in an optical-tweezing experiment and wish to know which direction they are being pulled.)

[image]

The picture below shows the relative sizes of images after passing through the aperture.
[image]

Comment: Surely if the object moves from A" to A' the size of the image will decrease and moving it from A' to A" will cause the size of the image to decrease?

Comment: Did you get +18 points for the question? I just want to check for personal reasons.

Comment: Yes, the images are decreasing in size from both A' and A'' until they reach A, since that is the focal point. So, I'm assuming there isn't really any way to tell?

Comment: I just added an image that might explain my previous comment

Answer (score 2):

**Use an iris in your lens tube.**

An iris close to the detector will distinguish between near defocused and far defocused images by their brightness. Looking at your diagram, you’d ideally want to place the iris at the focus spot for $B’’$, but anywhere close to the camera/eyepiece would in theory work. Close the iris down and monitor the brightness. If the image gets brighter as the particle is displaced, it’s moving toward the objective lens. If it gets uniformly darker, it’s moving away.